# Problem with background in IE, all other browser work excellent.... please help...i almost get fired

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

I have this problem with background in IE PC, all other browsers including Mac Safari work excellent.... please help...i almost get fired...

link is:

http://www.imageoneads.com/missiongallery/index.htm

Thanks so much

tran006

Comment: It looks fine to me in IE6... what part are you talking about?

Comment: Looks fine in IE8 too, what specifically is your problem?

Comment: you sure the user didnt have some sort of setting disabling images? table layouts - thats a no-no in the US/UK (and Germany as far as I am aware) for Disability Discrimination laws (UK - DDA, US- Section 508).

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Looks fine in ie6 through the web rendering @: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php?browser=ie6&url=http://www.imageoneads.com/missiongallery/index.htm

Comment: If this is a background issue, why is it a programming problem?  So, what is the problem?  You didn't get fired so you can't collect unemployment insurance?  You can't figure out which version of IE you need to test on?  There's nothing to go on here.

Answer (score 1):

I checked it with the help of **[IE-Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)** and it looked same in all versions IE starting from 5.5 to 8. Same was the result in other browsers too.

Comment: Kyle & Codeka

Thanks for your response.

Problems display "inventory page" - Only center part where list item in css display - Surrounding graphic disappeared in IE8 - All mac version look great ???

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. I figured it out. It my IE setting "compatibility view" was checked off. You are right. All looks fine. Tran006